# pcregrep with multiple capturing groups

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, docker

Having a problem with the -oX options in pcregrep. Specifying multiple such options with different numbers only outputs the last specified captured group.

**The Data:**

`docker ps | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +2 | xargs docker inspect`

outputs:

```
[{
"ID": "4e7f430263c33c25970134760ea96f9b57452680a8cfdf062270f5f7fe385135",
.... #lots of additional lines
"Ports": {
        "5000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                "HostPort": "5000"
            }
        ],
        "5984/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                "HostPort": "5984"
            }
        ]
    }
},{
#same as above, but with a different ID and HostPort 5000
}]
```

**The Idea**

`docker ps | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +2 | xargs docker inspect | pcregrep -M -o1 'ID":\s"(\w*)(?:\n|.)*?HostPort":\s"(\w)'`

outputs

```
4e7f430263c33c25970134760ea96f9b57452680a8cfdf062270f5f7fe385135
db35ce4b1fc7580ff43bacda5e961c4741c9447e97dbbdbf38218d068b0132af
```

and

`docker ps | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +2 | xargs docker inspect | pcregrep -M -o2 'ID":\s"(\w*)(?:\n|.)*?HostPort":\s"(\w*)'`

outputs

```
8000
5000
```

So far so good. Now I'd like to have these outputs combined on the sameline. `pcregrep -M -o` however outputs everything in between as well (it seems to ignore that the middle group is non capturing) and `pcregrep -M -o1 -o2` only outputs the second group - the second option seems to overwrite the first one. This being on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Any idea how to get the output

```
4e7f430263c33c25970134760ea96f9b57452680a8cfdf062270f5f7fe385135 8000
db35ce4b1fc7580ff43bacda5e961c4741c9447e97dbbdbf38218d068b0132af 5000
```

and still keeping it 'unixy' (preferably no perl/python/ruby scripts)?

Background: I want to automatically stop containers in docker that occupy specific ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone is wondering 10 years later...

`-o` is now a well-established part of `pcregrep`, and what's more, it comes with a friend: `--om-separator=text`.

So the answer to the original question is: add `--om-separator=" "` to `pcregrep`.

P.S. What I find weird, not all man pages sites list it, `pcregrep --help` does though.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to specify `-o` multiple times to `pcregrep` appears to be a very recent development ([version 8.32](http://www.pcre.org/changelog.txt), released 30 November 2012).  I'll assume your distro doesn't have this yet. :-)  So, using `awk` instead.  Also, replacing extraneous use of `tail` in the original with equivalent functionality in the first `awk` script.

```
docker ps | awk '(NR >= 2) { print $1 }' | xargs docker inspect | awk '($1~/"ID":/){gsub("\"|,","",$2);id=$2}; (id && $1~/"HostPort":/) {gsub("\"","",$2);print id " " $2;id=""}'
```